# Which tree is balance and AVL balanced?

Tags: binary-tree, avl-tree

From my understanding, a complete tree is a balanced tree that may not be AVL balanced.

A complete tree is one where all levels are completely filled except maybe the deepest, at depth n, the height of the tree needs to be as far left as possible.

Am I therefore right to say that both these trees are Complete and AVL balanced?

```
Example A: 
         4
        / \
       2   5
      /   /
     1   3

Example B:
         4
        / \
       2   5
      / \  
     1   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Example A is neither complete, nor AVL.

It is not complete because at the bottom level not all values are as far left as possible (there is a gap). If you would iterate the bottom level and include `null` for where the parent node has no corresponding child, it would be `2,null,3,null,...` while there should be no value occurring after such `null`.

It is not AVL, because it violates the order: no nodes in the right subtree of 4 should be less than 4.